# How to predict the class membership using the multinomial logistic regression?

Tags: categorical-data, prediction, multinomial-logit

I have the three classes and the true regression coefficients for two predictors and one intercept for each class as

```
R=3 #three class 
beta=matrix(c(-1.5,1,1.5,
      -0.5,1,-1.5,
      0,0,0), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = T)#
```

Third class is the reference category[all coefficients are zero].

I have the followoing predictors with five subjects

```
structure(list(X1 = c(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5), X2 = c(0.797644486414738, 
1.43023656974306, 1.57799081483507, 0.391320317833996, -1.31154404820595
), X3 = c(0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

    X1         X2   X3
1 -0.5  0.7976445  0.5
2  0.5  1.4302366  0.5
3 -0.5  1.5779908 -0.5
4  0.5  0.3913203 -0.5
5 -0.5 -1.3115440 -0.5
```

How can I determine the class membership for each row/id?

Comment: Multinomial logistic regression is aimed at estimating the _probability_ of class membership.  You can convert those probabilities into optimum decisions once you know the utility/loss/cost function, if you need decisions.

Comment: can you give an example please?

Comment: Start with https://discourse.datamethods.org/t/sensitivity-specificity-and-roc-curves-are-not-needed-for-good-medical-decision-making and https://fharrell.com/post/classification